# Looping through directories using a csh command

Tags: directory, tar, csh

I am trying to get a list of folders in my directory 'KEAX', and then dive into each one of them.

After entering each folder, I want to run the command:

```
foreach f(*.tar)
tar -xvf$f
end
```

After running this command, I want to back out, and then go into the next folder that is in 'KEAX' and run the same command as above. However, I am getting an error running the above command

Comment: Does it have to be csh or would bash or something else also be okay?

Comment: bash should be just as good

Answer (score 1):

This command should work. It searches for all `*.tar` files in the current directory recursively and `cd`s into its location in a Bash subshell and unpacks it there for each result:

```
find . -iname '*.tar' -exec bash -c 'cd "$(dirname "{}")" ; tar -xvf "$(basename "{}")"' \;
```

Comment: If this answer solves your question, please consider accepting it by clicking the grey check button on its left. You can take the short [tour] to learn some basics about how our site works. Thanks and welcome to Ask Ubuntu.